# suspend-then-hibernate behaviour when swap is insufficent

Tags: suspend, swap, hibernate

I'm having problems with system resume after suspend on a Ryzen build. If I suspend then wake a few minutes later, everything works fine. If I leave it a day or two, my system never wakes up despite fans and lights coming on when I tap the power button.

I discovered `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` which contains commented out defaults for sleep configuration, of the lines present these two stood out. Which make me wonder if suspend is working, but hibernate is not.

```
#AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
...
#HibernateDelaySec=180min
```

So I tried manually triggering `sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` and interestingly I get:

```
Failed to suspend system, hibernate later via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation
```

Fair enough, I have less swap than RAM so makes sense. So my question is this, what is the expected behaviour of `AllowSuspendThenHibernate` when swap space is not sufficient? Should it realise there's not enough swap and stay in a suspended state?

And as a corollary question, if it doesn't realise there's insufficient swap, should disabling hibernation and only allowing suspend solve my issue?

Comment: While this may not answer your question, personally I avoid `suspend` or `hibernate`because they write everything to the hard drive for fast wakeup. I've had problems before suddenly finding the hard drive hasn't been correctly purged and had to re-format it.

Comment: I didn't think that suspend wrote anything to the disk, everything in memory stays in memory just the system is told to enter a sleep (S3?) state. Hibernate, yes, that writes out to swap space.